# How can I use a value returned by a function in another application in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, wxpython

I want to know how can I return a value from an executable program developed in python, value that will be interpreted by another application. Also depending on what button is pressed the python application to shut down and return a specific value, which will be used in another script. I tried something, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Place some picture named `warning.jpg` in the script folder if you want to run it.

```
import wx
import gettext
import os
import time
global status

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "===WARNING!===",size=(1000,700), style =  wx.CAPTION )
        self.Centre()
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(1)
        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
        print(self.currentDirectory)
        warning = wx.StaticText (panel, -1, "Warning!!! Before you test, be sure you follow the instructions from the picture!", (150,5))
        font = wx.Font(15, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        warning.SetFont(font)
        try:
            image_file = 'warning.jpg'
            self.image = wx.Image(image_file,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            self.bitmap_image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.image, pos=(10,30), size=(700,350))
        except:
             wx.MessageBox("Verify that in path:"+self.currentDirectory+"\n"+"you have a picture named: \"warning\" of JPG OR BMP type")
             quit()       
        self.DoneButton=wx.Button(panel,label='DONE!' ,pos=(150,500), size=(200,100))
        self.DoneButton.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.DoneButton.SetFont(wx.Font(15, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Done, self.DoneButton)      
        self.CancelButton=wx.Button(panel,label='CANCEL!' ,pos=(500,500), size=(200,100))
        self.CancelButton.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.CancelButton.SetFont(wx.Font(15, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Cancel, self.CancelButton)

    def Done(self, event):
        self.statusbar.PushStatusText('Done!!! Exiting...')
        print("Done! Exiting...")
        status = "ok"
        return status
        ##also to kill the program after the button is pressed 

    def Cancel(self, event):
        self.statusbar.PushStatusText('Exiting...')
        print("Cancel! Exiting...")
        status = "cancel"
        return status
        ##also to kill the program after the button is pressed 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app")
    app = wx.App()
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: if you're not time limited, just write the output of the first script in a file and read it in the second script

Comment: Stéphane, not an option for me, it needs to be as fast as possible

Comment: How about `os.pipe()`?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what it is that you want to achieve. Is there more than one script running at a time? Should the result be available after the script has terminated? If there is more than one script, do they have to running at the same time? Is there a server, client relationship. Without specifics, there are too many options to be able to provide a decent answer. Pipes, Sockets, Files etc

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Basically I would want that my executable developed in python to be able to return a value when a button is pressed. Well this executable will be used in another program (spectrum software) that has the option of loading an external program(cvi,dll,.exe,etc) and reading the returned values. Spectrum program it's calling my python executable, so yes they have to run at the same time

Comment: Look at `sys.exit(n)` where n is an integer, if the script is to terminate or `sys.stdout.write('button1')` for example if the script is to continue. Although your basic premise does not look particularly solid.

Comment: And if i use sys.exit(some value) for 1st button and another sys.exit with different value for the 2nd button, is there a possibility to catch/interpret that value with another program,script, etc. just after the first program was terminated?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to our comment discussion and in really simple terms:
Calling program:

```
from subprocess import call
print("executing external code")
return_code = call('python3 a1.py', shell=True)
if return_code == 5:
    print("Code executed correctly result: ",return_code)
elif return_code == 42:
    print("Code excuted correctly result: ", return_code)
else:
    print("Code failed")

return_code = call('python3 a1.py "parameter"', shell=True)
if return_code == 5:
    print("Code executed correctly result: ",return_code)
elif return_code == 42:
    print("Code excuted correctly result: ", return_code)
else:
    print("Code failed")
```

Called program (named a1.py):

```
import sys
x=sys.argv
print("doing some work")
if len(x) > 1:
    sys.exit(42)
else:
    sys.exit(5)
```

Result:

```
executing external code
doing some work
Code executed correctly result:  5
doing some work
Code excuted correctly result:  42
```